# Calculating x-acceleration (east ), and y acceleration(north) of a running Vehicle

Tags: android, math, physics

I want to calculate the acceleration of a running vehicle.
Until now I am able to get the acceleration along the heading vector using below formula

```
a = (velocity(now)-velocity(previous))/time m/s^2
```

Example: a car travels 50 meters in 3 sec and in the next 3 sec the car travels 60 meters more.

```
v1=50/3=16.66 m/s
v2=60/3=20 m/s
    
acceleration : 
acc=(20-16.66)/6=4.66/6= -.55 m/s^2
```

But I need to get the acceleration along with both x and y direction.

I required the x-acceleration which is the east acceleration, as well as the y acceleration which is the north acceleration.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: total x distance / (total time)^2  doesnt work ?

Comment: are younsure that you dont want to calculate the acceleation in driving direction, and the transversal acceleration instead? whatbdoes the N accel help if the vehicle is drivong SW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use trigonometry to get the components. East/West/X would be COSINE and North/South/Y would be SINE.

```
xAccel = cos(angle) * acceleration
yAccel = sin(angle) * acceleration
```

Where angle is the movement direction. For example if the angle was 90 degrees pointing straight north, then cos(90 degrees) would be 0 meaning there is no X axis acceleration.

Comment: +1 from me - You can't solve this problem without knowing about vectors.